# Shiro.ini file configuration but in Java class?

Tags: java, shiro

I want to know if its possible to configure Shiro without the shiro.ini file, I mean, instead of using the INI file, what if I need to make the Shiro config to be hardcoded in a Java class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The documentation says how to do it:

http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-ProgrammaticConfiguration

Answer (score 2):

see [Credentials Matching](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-CredentialsMatching)

or use jdbc custom realm [here](http://blog.pinateknoloji.com/shiro-jdbc-realm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS );
context.setContextPath( "/" );
context.addEventListener( new EnvironmentLoaderListener() );

// Add root ShiroFilter, all remaining filters and filter chains are defined in shiro.ini's [urls] section.
FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder( new ShiroFilter() );
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( new MockServlet() );

EnumSet<DispatcherType> types = EnumSet.allOf( DispatcherType.class );
context.addFilter( filterHolder, "/*", types );
context.addFilter( new FilterHolder( new TestFilter() ), "/*", types );
context.addServlet( servletHolder, "/*" );
```

And for shiro.ini file refer [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager) doc: